# How to identify whether a problem can be solved with Tail-recursion or not in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

How can I identify whether a problem statement can be solved with tail recursion or not. Is there any characteristics of a problem by which one can identify that?

Comment: it's just an assumption that every problem which can be solve with recursion can be solved with tail recursion yet there is no methamatical proof for that so, you can just try to solve it with tail recursion.

Comment: @RamanMishra It's not just an assumption https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41768/can-any-recursion-implementation-be-written-as-tail-recursion
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/is-this-a-generic-way-to-convert-any-recursive-procedure-to-tail-recursion

Comment: @DmytroMitin thank you but actually I didn’t find any mathematical proof for that so I thought we didn’t find anything which can be done by recursion and not by tail recursion till now so I said it’s an assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Tail-recursion can express loops, so any problem that can be solved by a loop, can also be solved by tail-recursion:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def myWhile(condition: => Boolean)(body: => Unit): Unit = 
  if (condition) { body; myWhile(condition)(body) }

var i = 0

myWhile { i < 10 } { i += 1; println(i) }
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
```

In particular, expressing *iteration* is very natural with tail-recursion:

```
def processElement[A, B](el: A)(restOfTheElements: Traversable[A]): B = {
  doSomethingWithEl
  val (nextElement, newRest) = doSomethingToGetNextElement(restOfTheElements)
  processElement(nextElement)(newRest)
}
```

Event loops (e.g. a GUI, a web server, an operating system kernel) are naturally tail-recursive:

```
def processEvent[A](event: A)(eventPump: EventPump[A]): Unit = {
  doSomethingWithEvent
  processEvent(eventPump.nextEvent)(eventPump)
}
```

Also, a language which contains only `WHILE` loops is Turing-complete, so tail-recursion can *at least* be used to compute every Turing-computable function over the natural numbers.